# How do I get rid of the infinite news feed on Yahoo home page?

Tags: yahoo

Yahoo is my home page. Normally it shows a few news items in several categories. But now it shows a never-ending list of news items that seem to be in no particular order or categories. If I scroll down, it just keeps showing more.  I don't see any kind of customize or reset button that allows me to change it back to the standard/default view. Help!

Windows 7 Professional. Chrome browser.

Comment: You've mentioned nothing about your operating system, browser, or anything about what you've tried to fix it, so I'm voting to close this question as "off-topic".

Comment: Can you provide more detail? Like what browser you're using and whether you're signed in or not. I do not see the same Yahoo homepage experience.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome web store has an extension called as "Page Eraser", using which parts of any page can be erased and saved. Whenever you open the page again, those particular parts won't show up.